# Zend_Form, setAttrib('escape',false) not working, help

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, escaping

I am using Zend_Form and I would like one of my elements to not escape. I have the following code, I think it should not escape but it does without fail:

In form class:

```
    $btc_name = $this->createElement('text','btc_name');
    $btc_name->setLabel('Company Name')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setAttrib('size',45)
        ->setAttrib('escape',false)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
```

Output html:

```
<dt id="btc_name-label"><label for="btc_name" class="required">Company Name</label></dt> <dd id="btc_name-element"><input type="text" name="btc_name" id="btc_name" value="Joe\'s Tire Warehouse" size="45" /></dd>
```

You can see the form in action with a print_r of the $formData and getValue of the field here: **Link Removed**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Joe Chin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's the backslash you're referring to, it's likely to be PHP that's adding this, not Zend Framework. Check your php.ini file and look for a setting called magic_quotes_gpc - you want this to be off (unless you have other things relying on it). If you can't alter your php.ini file but are using mod_php, you can override this in a .htaccess file:

```
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php for some background, and why it is bad.

Comment: Tim, That worked perfect! My hair is screaming thanks. - JoeChin